# How can I remove paper from glass?

Tags: windows, glass

I tried to remove glass-paper from a window in my house, but when I try it tears. How can I remove it without it tearing?

Comment: What is "glass-paper"?  Is that some special kind of glass?  Or does that mean some paper adheres to glass?

Comment: @wallyk  it is a type of fancy paper that stick over glass to reduce the transparency of glass, or make it look fancy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to remember using Windex.. Long soak, cover with plastic wrap for 30-60 min, scrape carefully with wide (6 to 8 inch) putty knife or drywall blade or wall paper knife.

I was able to save my first new vehicle sticker.

Comment: i tried and it worked great and i successfully saved my glass, a few clinch of stickers were left that then remove easily by razor blade..

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use metal on the window, I just ruined one of my double pane windows getting off the manufacturer sticker (I used a razor blade).

Soak with a sovent, water...windex....etc..., wait for the solvent to penetrate the paper and glue (long time), then "scoop" off with something non-metalic. Plastic WILL take it off easily if you wait long enough and will not scratch the glass. You might have to sand the end of the plastic to give it an edge (so it scoops easily), but it wont scratch the glass!

Answer (score 0):

Try warming it with a hair dryer first

Answer (score 0):

Soak that glass in warm water and then rub it with a brush or wire scrubber.