# How do I remove huge gluey sticker tape on glass?

Tags: windows, glass

I'm asking for my cousin in Hong Kong, whose little children stuck this window sticker onto the glass. We read [How do I remove the gluey residue left by gaffer tape on glass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/48915), https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/30948, [Removing Tuck Tape from an unfinished window frame](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7098), but nothing works! Please see the picture with my labels below.

We tried vegetable oil, dishwash detergent, rubbing (isopropyl) alcohol, and vinegar. The only solution is to use our nails to tear off a litte piece of the tape, a tiny piece by tiny piece. Please help! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you need more pictures.

Comment: We also tried http://www.diynot.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=241015, http://homeguides.sfgate.com/sticky-tape-off-windows-22999.html, http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf347238.tip.html,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good brand of [orange oil (limonene) cleaner](https://www.google.com/search?q=orange%20oil%20cleaner&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) takes care of most of my tape problems. Some tapes, such as window-tinting sheets, are thermosetting, and removal requires heating. I used a clothes steamer/razor blade on the tinted windows of my Honda. That worked well. See method two, [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Window-Tint).

Comment: +1 for razor scraper answer; remove the sticker mechanically then use solvent on the glue residue.

Answer (score 1):

My cousin managed to solve it. He used [a razor blade scraper](https://www.google.com/search?q=window+scraper&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=gyzAVKabFY-yogTY7YLwAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1024&bih=651#tbm=isch&q=paint+scraper+window&spell=1&imgdii=_)

[image]

and [something called 綠水](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%B6%A0%E6%B0%B4&biw=1024&bih=651&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=XCnAVJ_VOY7eoATgoYH4Ag&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_) in Chinese.  I think it's just a kind of bleach used only in Hong Kong.

The trick is to use the razor scraper while spraying the sticker with the bleach, so you need to scrape wetly. It doesn't work if you only use the razor scraper and scrape dryly.

He found a "putty knife", underneath, completely useless.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have already tried other approaches, this may not work any longer but I have had great success with a blow dryer (hair dryer).
Just warm it up and use a sharp object to start an edge of the sticky tape, gently lifting it as you aim the hair dryer at it (slowly moving it back and forth).  The heat generally releases the sticky adhesive so you can peel it off!

I'd follow this process with some Goof Off over the tackiness that will likely remain on the glass surface.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Heat generally helps a lot - softens the adhesive so it pulls away easily. Depending on the adhesive, cold also works (but not in Hong Kong - never gets to -30 there).

Regarding solvents / cleaning chemicals etc. Solvents only work on things they are chemically compatible with. There is no "magic glue remover" unless you work your way up to spectacularly dangerous chemicals like straight chromic acid. Try one, if it doesn't like the glue in question try another. If you can't pronounce it on the first try, definitely get gloves and a respirator.

Comment: Spray on chromic acid would do amusing things to wood or metal window casings.